# What would be a good way to implement a set collection with weak references, compares by reference, and is also sortable in Java?

Tags: java, android, data-structures, collections, dalvik

I want to have an object that allows other objects of a specific type to register themselves with it. Ideally it would store the references to them in some sort of set collection and have .equals() compare by reference rather than value. It shouldn't have to maintain a sort at all times, but it should be able to be sorted before the collection is iterated over.

Looking through the Java Collection Library, I've seen the various features I'm looking for on different collection types, but I am not sure about how I should go about using them to build the kind of collection I'm looking for.

This is Java in the context of Android if that is significant.

Comment: What do you mean with "separate references to the same object"?

Comment: Afaik separate references to the same object are possible in Java only in very limited cases, e.g. when serialization is involved. Do you really mean this scenario or do you mean "equal" objects when talking about the "same object"? In case of the former, where you can't rely on comparing references in order to test for object identity, I guess this can be decided only if the objects carry unique identifiers.

Comment: Sorry I meant something like an IdentityHashMap, using reference equality rather than object equality. That is, .equals() just does ==

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Java's built-in tree-based collections won't work.**

To illustrate, consider a tree containing weak references to nodes 'B', 'C', and 'D':

```
   C
B     D
```

Now let the weak reference 'C' get collected, leaving null behind:

```
   -
B     D
```

Now insert an element into the tree. The TreeMap/TreeSet doesn't have sufficient information to select the left or right subtree. If your comparator says null is a small value, then it will be incorrect when inserting 'A'. If it says null is a large value, it will be incorrect when inserting 'E'.

**Sort on demand is a good choice.**

A more robust solution is to use an `ArrayList<WeakReference<T>>` and to implement a `Comparator<WeakReference<T>>` that delegates to a `Comparator<T>`. Then call `Collections.sort()` prior to iteration.

Android's `Collections.sort` uses [TimSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) behind-the-scenes and so it runs quite efficiently if the input is already partially sorted.

Comment: The original question didn't specify weak references.

Comment: Could I use an IdentityHashMap in my containing class in order to avoid the cost of .contains()? When an object registers with the class, it could just put it in the ArrayList and the IdentityHashMap. Duplicate checks done before an object is added to the ArrayList could just check to see if a reference to the object exists as a key in the hash map.

Comment: @Jared it's in the title of the post.

Comment: @VWD2 That'll work. Or put duplicates into the ArrayList and null them out when you iterate?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the collections classes are a level of abstraction below what you're looking for?  It sounds like the end product you want is a cache with the ability to iterate in a user-defined sort order.  If so, perhaps the cache interface in the Google Guava library is close enough to what you want:

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/trunk/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/Cache.java

At a glance, it looks like CacheBuilder in that package doesn't allow you to build an implementation with user-defined iteration order.  However, it *does* provide a Map view that might be good enough for your needs:

```
List<Thing> cachedThings = Lists.newArrayList(cache.asMap().values());
Collections.sort(cachedThings, YOUR_THING_COMPARATOR);
for (Thing thing : cachedThings) { ... }
```

Even if this isn't exactly what you want, the classes in that package might give you some useful insights re: using References with Collections.

Answer (score -1):

DISCLAIMER: This was a comment but it got kinda big, sorry if it doesn't solve your problem:

#### References in Java

Just to clarify what I mean when I say reference, since it isn't really a term commonly used in Java: Java does not *really* use references or pointers. It uses a kind of pseudo-reference that can be (and is by default) assigned to the special `null` instance. That's one way to explain it anyway. In Java, these pseudo-references are the only way that an `Object` can be handled. When I say reference, I mean these pseudo-references.

#### Sets

Any `Set` implementation will not allow two references to the same object to be included in it since it uses identity equality for this check. That violates the mathematical concept of a set. The Java `Set`s ignore any attempt to add duplicate references.

You mention a `Map` in your comment though... Could you clarify what kind of collection you are after? And why you need that kind of equality checking within it? Are you thinking in C++ terms? I'll try to edit my answer to be more helpful then :)

EDIT: I thought that might have been your goal ;) So a `TreeSet` should do the trick then! I would not get concerned about performance until there *is* a performance issue. Simplicity is fantastic for readability, maintenance and preventing bugs. If performance does become a problem, ideally you should profile your code and only optimize the areas that are *proven* to be the problem.

Comment: As long as a set uses identity equality for its check when you attempt to add elements to it, that is what I meant. I suppose I could use a sorted set in that case, but I don't don't really need the overhead of maintaining an order at all times. It just needs to be able to be sorted and iterated over with that sort at a specific time.

Comment: My plan is to have the containing class have a property like 'isSorted' that is initially set to true, but is set to false every time something is added to the set. That way, when I need to iterate over the set in in a particular order, it can just check the property beforehand to see if it needs to re-sort the set before it iterates over it.

I would be iterating over the set a lot more often than I would be adding or removing elements from it.

Comment: I assume TreeSet doesn't use weak references?

Comment: Nope, there's no such thing in Java.